How to filter Solana log subscriptions
I am trying to only listen to transactions regarding ONE specific program and only one specific instruction.
For example I only want to see logs of transactions that executed the "create" instruction in Program X.
This is my code so far. Not working since it is not filtering.
  const subscriptionId = connection.onLogs(
    PROGRAM_ID,
    (logInfo) => {
      console.log("New log entry detected:", logInfo);

      // Check logs for "create" instruction
      for (const log of logInfo.logs) {
        if (isCreateInstruction(log)) {
          console.log("Detected 'create' instruction in transaction:", logInfo.signature);

          // Process the transaction (e.g., fetch details)
          processTransaction(logInfo.signature);
        }
      }
    },
    "confirmed"
  );


Can we see an example log and the implementation of isCreateInstruction()?
